# Maven is using incorrect location for downloading plugin pom

Tags: maven-2, nexus

(This question is asked on Maven User mailing list too)

I have recently faced a strange problem, that I cannot even able to judge the cause or source of problem.  It will be great if someone can give me some direction:

(The story may be a bit long)

I am using Nexus 1.8.0 as our company's repository manager.  I use it as proxy of external repo, and hosting our own repository.
There are many repositories in Nexus.  I have one repository group (let's call it **PUBLIC**) which groups all public repositories, including maven central, codehaus etc.
There is another repository group (let's call it **EXT**) which we put 3rd party artifacts.

In our project, we used `org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin`.
Due to a bug at that time, instead of using the publicly available `org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1`, I have fixed the bug and deploy it to our **EXT** repository, and called it `org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1`  (i.e. used a new version number `1.0-alpha-1.1` instead of `1.0-alpha-1`)

This have been running fine for several years.

However recently a new developer tries to get the code and build, using Maven 2.2.1.  Strange things happened: the build failed.  By inspecting result of mvn -X clean install, it states that POM of `native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1` cannot be downloaded from **PUBLIC**, therefore it will use a default emtpy POM, which cause the build problem.

By inspecting the local repository, I found that only the JAR of `native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1` was downloaded.  I am sure that there is no `native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1` in **PUBLIC** repository, and the SHA of the JAR matches with `native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1` in **EXT**.  It seems that, Maven is capable to download the JAR correctly from **EXT** repo, but when it tries to download the POM afterwards, Maven mistakenly think that it should be downloaded from **PUBLIC**.  Because **PUBLIC** do not contains `1.0-alpha-1.1`, Maven assume there is no POM.

I have **EXT** repo defined before **PUBLIC** in my settings.xml. What even more strange is, I tried to block accessing in Nexus for `native2ascii-maven-plugin` from **PUBLIC**.  Maven, instead of getting the POM from repository **EXT**, it get from **central** directly.  At last I add **PUBLIC** as mirror for **central**, and Maven can build correctly, because **EXT** is the the only repo that contains `native2ascii-maven-plugin`.  Maven seems tries to download the POM from every repository else which contains `native2ascii-maven-plugin` in despite of the version number, except from **EXT**

I simply cannot understand why this will happen.  This have been used for years, and it used to be fine even several weeks before (I have other new developers, who can correctly download the plugin, several weeks ago).  May anyone guide me the possible cause of the problem?  I have neither changed anything in my repo, nor changed version of Maven.  Why Maven's "download" behavior suddenly changed?

Comment: What repositories do you reference from your project's POM? Do you have a `~/.m2/settings.xml` file?

Comment: I have several repo in my settings.xml but all of them points to our internal repository manager (Nexus).  The repositories in settings.xml are in fact repository group defined in Nexus, each repo group contains multiple actual remote/locally-hosted repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I managed to find out the "cause" of the problem.  It is due to my fault, combined with still-unknown behavior of Maven.  I add this as an answer to ease future reference for other people.

They key problem is that I missed plugin version for this specific project (I did put corresponding pluginManagement for other projects, and other plugins for this project... I wonder how come I made this mistake this time)

The way to reproduce the problem:

1. A separate repository to store the plugin (in my case, `org.codehaus.mojo:native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1.1`)
2. In project POM, add plugin, without version.  For example,

   ```
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```
3. in settings.xml, avoid defining mirrors (i.e. the settings.xml contains list of repositories and pluginRepositories only)

With such setup, first purge the local repository.  Then build the project.  After build, inspect the directory in local repository for that plugin (in my case `.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\native2ascii-maven-plugin\1.0-alpha-1.1`), you will find only the JAR presents, without corresponding POM. (Caused by Maven successfully get the plugin JAR corresponding to the pluginRepositories in settings.xml, but trying to get the POM from a weird location)

With the same setup, put the version in project POM, clean up the local repo, and build again.  Everything is fine now.

The reason for work fine even for a recently clean CI environment, is probably due to other "correct" project made the plugin downloaded correctly, which can be used by this "incorrect" project.  A periodic purge in local repository in CI won't necessary help much on this too because for that many projects, the chance is always very high for other "correct" project build earlier than that "incorrect" project.

The reason behind such behavior of Maven is still unknown, but at least in a "correct" POM (with plugin version correctly declared), Maven works fine.  I will raise this as a issue for Maven though.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say.

First my theory on why it no longer works. I am guessing this "worked for years" because at one time it worked, and afterwards everything was in your local repository (`<home>/.m2/repository`). Later, something broke, but you never noticed because you had everything local. The new developer did not have a populated local repository so when they built for the first time, they had failures.

Now my suggestion which may not work out for you. When using Nexus, I think its best to create a single "group" repository that links in all other repositories, and configure the group to order the priority of the linked repositories. So for you, in the group, you would list EXT first, then PUBLIC. Your POMs and/or settings would reference only the group repository. This may just duplicate what you are already doing through other means, but at least it is moving the ordering rules up into Nexus. I would rename your local repository (so you can revert back if necessary) and try re-building to see if everything resolves correctly.

You might want to consider a continuous build tool like Hudson that periodically deletes its own local repository so you can catch issues like this sooner.

Comment: yes the local repo is making the difference on my and new developer's behavior but what I am concerning is why Maven is resolving things like this. It is fine several months ago (coz I have migrated our CI server and I have a clean env to build, and everything is fine).  In fact I have made several groups already but there are reasons that we don't prefer making up one mega repo group with all internal and external repo.  Having a periodic cleanup in local repo is definitely good idea but, the problem still exists, which I have no idea on the right way to solve...

Comment: and, Maven always aims at "reproducible build".  The current behavior seems something ruining this idea.  I definitely want to have some clues on the possible cause of the strange behavior so that I can avoid in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off by agreeing with SingleShot in that Continuous Integration - even a simple smoke test where you simply compile and run unit tests on the trunk - would have prevented you getting into the situation of assuming that the because the build works on one machine, it does not work on the other.

> This have been running fine for several years.

That's the kicker with Maven repositories - all you need to do is download it once succesfully, and you'll be forever good to go. Just because it's been working successfully from your local repository doesn't mean it was working.

> It is fine several months ago (coz I have migrated our CI server and I have a clean env to build, and everything is fine).

Interesting. So my theory would be then to go and make sure the new developer is set up correctly - that the settings.xml file is in place and is being read (I've had instances that the settings.xml is THERE, but in the wrong place!). It's a simple one, but Maven does not fail if there's no settings.xml, it just uses a default that may have you seeing ghosts.

Comment: In fact after the new developer encountered the problem, originally I cannot reproduce (bcoz of the existing libs in local repo).  After I manually wipe out my local repo, the same problem happens to me too, for which is surely having the correct setting (coz I have been using it for long time, without any update recently).  And for my case, maven will fail without settings.xml, because the dependencies are not available from the default maven central repo.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you use maven 2.2.1 and I can only ask you to doublecheck, we had some strange behavior concerning downloading jars from internal repo that was caused by OSX Lion update that comes with maven3. Our fix was to redeploy affected project.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is Maven 2.2.1.  However I think it is worth to try redeploying.  Just curious, what kind of strange behavior you have encountered?

Comment: Artifact was committed with one groupId until version X and then with another, and maven3 refused to download it. There also seems to be something specific about this artifact, because other artifacts in similar position were fetched properly. That's probably why we tried redeploy in the first place.